# Get Records By Todays Date And Before Current Time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to query some records and am looking to return only records that have a date of today, but also are before the current time.

I have the first part sorted out by using the following clause to return only records for today.

```
WHERE TRUNC(my_date_time) = TRUNC(sysdate)
```

How would I modify this to only get records before the current system time as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about inequalities?

```
WHERE my_date_time >= TRUNC(sysdate) AND
      my_date_time < sysdate
```

Comment: You could also use BETWEEN to shorten the WHERE clause a bit:  WHERE my_date_time BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) and sysdate

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
    Select * from table   Where  
     TRUNC(my_date_time) = 
    TRUNC(sysdate) And 
     TO_CHAR(my_date_time, 
      'HH24:MI:SS' ) <= 
      TO_CHAR(sysdate, 
      ' HH24:MI:SS' )
```

[image]

Comment: It isnt because the type at both the sides  of  relational operator remains the same

Comment: You need to use HH24 to get hours from 0 to 23, otherwise  2 pm (14 hours) is less than 8 am (08 hours).!

Comment: Note that this approach prevents you from using an index on `my_date_time` unlike Gordon's answer.

Comment: Yes it does but I think if we see the data it would not be a huge dataset so this approach wont cost much.

Comment: There's no good reason here to be converting dates to string values for comparison purposes.

Comment: You have any other query if you can post which is different from Gordons that compares date. I agree with the Justin Dave's point that it prevents index matching hence can be slow for huge data sets but I strongly disagree to your comment @Jeffrey Kemp I will again say conversion of dates was on both sides of the relational operator to make it  valid and giving a downvote with no proper reason but just a random thought was irrelevant i suppose.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't make it "valid". When you convert both sides to a string, you are no longer comparing dates - you are comparing strings. Oracle has built-in support for comparing dates directly, there is simply *no reason* to convert to strings to compare dates. It's illogical to do so and that's why the downvote is appropriate.

Comment: By the way, your code is getting the *month* (`MM`) instead of *minutes* (`MI`) so it will be incorrect *some of the time*.... :)

Answer (score -2):

If column "**my_date_time**" is of type DATE, and need compare using SYSDATE function then you only need:

```
WHERE my_date_time<=sysdate
```

If column "**my_date_time**" is of type DATE, and need compare with other variable or column of type DATE for example named "**other_date**"

```
 where my_date_time>=trunc(other_date)
   and my_date_time<trunc(other_date)+1
```

Comment: what if the date is not sysdate will it be valid check op's query again